# Row numbering (@i := @i + 1) doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT posts.post_id,
       members.member_joined,
       @i := @i + 1
FROM   posts LEFT JOIN members
             ON posts.member_id = members.member_id
WHERE posts.topic_id = 1
ORDER BY posts.post_created ASC;
```

That query returns the following result set:

```
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
| post_id | member_joined       | @i := @i + 1 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            1 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|       3 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            4 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|       4 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            5 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|       5 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            6 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      14 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            7 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      17 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            8 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      35 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            9 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      37 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            2 | -- What's the 2 doing down here?
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|      42 | 2014-10-14 20:28:15 |            3 | -- Ditto.
+---------+---------------------+--------------+
```

As you can see, for some unknown to me reason, the numbers 2 and 3 appear at the very bottom of the result set while they're not supposed to.

If I comment out the line **members.member_joined,** like so:

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT posts.post_id,
       -- members.member_joined,
       @i := @i + 1
FROM   posts LEFT JOIN members
             ON posts.member_id = members.member_id
WHERE posts.topic_id = 1
ORDER BY posts.post_created ASC;
```

The result set now is as expected:

```
+---------+--------------+
| post_id | @i := @i + 1 |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            1 |
+---------+--------------+
|       3 |            2 |
+---------+--------------+
|       4 |            3 |
+---------+--------------+
|       5 |            4 |
+---------+--------------+
|      14 |            5 |
+---------+--------------+
|      17 |            6 |
+---------+--------------+
|      35 |            7 |
+---------+--------------+
|      37 |            8 |
+---------+--------------+
|      42 |            9 |
+---------+--------------+
```

I just can't wrap my head around this. What might be wrong?

Comment: The results you expect to be returned depend on an *order of operations* which is not guaranteed by MySQL. The query could be written differently to "cause" MySQL to perform operations in a different order. But even with a query re-write, the MySQL Reference Manual **warns** that the behavior we observe with this usage of user-defined variables is **not** *guaranteed.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

most likely your order by is causing the count to be off.. ORDER BY is executed after the select is finsihed so it can reorder your count.. try putting it in a sub query.

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT post_id, member_joined, @i := @i + 1
FROM
(   SELECT p.post_id, m.member_joined
    FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN members m ON p.member_id = m.member_id
    WHERE p.topic_id = 1
    ORDER BY p.post_created ASC
)t;
```

Think of it this way.. SELECT to WHERE are pulling from the table... so any specific requirements can be in the WHERE.. GROUP BY to the end are after the request has finished and you are altering the results that came back... so thats why the order by can cause the issues... when you include the member joined in the select it returns results that get counted and then reordered by date

### NOTE:

MySQL [**DOCS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) is quite clear on this:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
> and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
> results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
> evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
> may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
> in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
> releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might
> think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment
> second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a
> GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an
> execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

Comment: Exactly how I would have rewritten the query, and very good explanation on the order by after the records already processed and reordered.

Comment: +1. The results that OP expects returned depend on *an order of operations* that is not guaranteed by MySQL. Let's add a note that the query in this answer "works" because it causes MySQL to perform some operations before it performs other operations. But the documentation gives specific **warning** that this behavior we observe (with user-defined variables) is **not** *guaranteed*, even with the query re-write.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem earlier. Changing `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` solved it.

Details are here:
https://pastebin.com/br3TNFBb